# Get keys from multidimentional array by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to get all "top level" keys from multidimensional array by searching the "bottom level" values. Here is an example of the array:

```
$list = array (
    'person1' => array(
           'personal_id' => '1',
           'short_information' => 'string',
           'books_on_hand' => array(
                         'Book 1',
                         'Book 2',
                         'Book 3',
                        )
     ),
     'person2' => array(
           'personal_id' => '2',
           'short_information' => 'string',
           'books_on_hand' => array(
                         'Book 4',
                         'Book 2',
                         'Book 5',
                        )
     ),
     'person3' => array(
           'personal_id' => '3',
           'short_information' => 'string',
           'books_on_hand' => array(
                         'Book 4',
                         'Book 2',
                         'Book 1',
                         'Book 3',
                        )
     ),
     //etc...
);
```

I want to know all persons who have "Book 2" on hand. I can get that information by loop like this:

```
foreach ($list as $person => $info){
   $check = array_search( 'Book 2', array_column($info, 'books_on_hand') );
   if ( $check !== false ){
      $results .= 'Name: '.$person; 
      $results .= 'ID: '.$info['personal_id'];
      //get other infos other stuff, if necessary
   }
}
```

The problem is, that `foreach` in this case is very heavy on memory and only grows more when array has a thousand+ entries.  It needs to run through all of the persons, even if only 3 persons at the very top of the array have "Book 2".

I have been trying to optimize it by getting persons with "Book 2" using built-in functions like `array_search`, `array_keys`, `array_column` and only then run `foreach` for persons found, but I had no luck with getting "top level" keys.

Is it possible to optimize or use built-in function to search multidimensional array?

Comment: Where does `$list` come from? Where is it generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to filter it first.  Now your result is structured like `$list` but it only contains elements with the needed book:

```
$find   = 'Book 2';
$result = array_filter($list, function($v) use($find) {
                                  return in_array($find, $v['books_on_hand']);  
                              });
```

If all you're interested in is the person key and `personal_id` then this:

```
$find   = 'Book 2';
$result = array_map(function($v) use($find) {
                       if(in_array($find, $v['books_on_hand'])) {
                           return $v['personal_id'];
                       }
                    }, $list);
```

Will return something like this for persons with the needed book:

```
Array
(
    [person1] => 1
    [person2] => 2
    [person3] => 3
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this looks very close to what I'm looking for, only I actually have one more depth, so I used in_array($find, array_column($v['books_on_hand'], 'book_name')) - gives everything correctly, just not gives 'person1', 'person2' keys.

Comment: This works with the array provided.  If there is another depth it isn't shown in your posted array.  So yes, just add the `array_column()` to the `in_array()`.  Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, It works correctly, I misleaded myself... it is giving top level key, thank you!